# Difference between having two networks with cascading LAN-to-Wan (two routers total) and "two" networks with "Y-Configuration" (three routers total)

Tags: networking, router, lan

I'm trying to have two separate networks, and I've seen that some people advocate for the "Y-Configuration" type connections, where you have a "master" router and two "slaves", where the master and the slaves are connected by LAN-to-WAN (and the master has DHCP off). [See this for more info](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/33700-42-ultimate-modem-router-setup-thread).

However, my understanding is that two routers in a cascading LAN-to-WAN configuration already have two separate networks. So what is the difference in performance between these two types of creating two (effective) networks? (I understand that technically the "Y" is three networks, but only two are meant to be "used").

Also explaining the advantages and disadvantages between the two is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume every router performs NAT on its own. If I get you right, you're talking about:

Three-router setup:

```
Outer router
 Inner router a
  Device A1
  Device A2
  …
 Inner router b
  Device B1
  Device B2
  …
```

Two-router setup:

```
Outer router
 Device O1
 Device O2
 …
 Inner router
  Device I1
  Device I2
  …
```

The main difference:

- Where there are three routers no `A` device can initiate communication with any `B` device without `Inner router b` being configured to allow this (e.g. port forwarding). And by symmetry: no `B` device can initiate…
- Where there are two routers no `O` device can initiate communication with any `I` device without `Inner router` being configured to allow this (e.g. port forwarding). **But** any `I` device can initiate communication with any `O` device (unless some firewall disallows this, but this is not by default).

> my understanding is that two routers in a cascading LAN-to-WAN configuration already have two separate networks

Not quite. **In two-router setup** `I` devices can reach `O` devices, so **the networks are not completely separated.**

> what is the difference in performance between these two types

When connecting to the outside (like to the Internet), `O` devices will undergo one NAT (at least, i.e. when there are no additional NATs beyond your `Outer router`). `A`, `B` and `I` devices will undergo two NATs (again: at least). This extra NAT will add some latency. In most cases it will be negligible, however e.g. hardcore gamers would prefer to play multiplayer from `O` position.

You may or may not experience the difference in throughput, it depends on your particular routers and their sequence. The general rule is: an extra link in chain can decrease the throughput or not affect it; it will never increase it.

> explaining the advantages and disadvantages between the two is welcomed

Another practical difference I can think of is when you want to forward a port to make one of your devices reachable from the Internet. Port forwarding to an `O` device involves `Outer router` configuration only. Port forwarding to an `A`, `B` or `I` device requires changes in configuration of two routers; these changes must correspond to each other. This makes the entire setup a little more complicated.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for the answer. But now I'm a little confused with the "However, computers that are connected to the main router will not be able to communicate with the secondary router, and vice versa since there are two (2) different networks." statement made here: https://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=132275